# Pass string, containing a slash as get-param

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm wondering if it's possible to parse a string containing an URL as `GET` parameter using `Mod-Rewrite` through `CakePHP`. Do I have to pass this via `$this->request->data (POST)`?

Is it common to set Routes for such cases or would you either recommend splitting the URL into separate parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slash in $_GET? Woudn't that just be a query string containing such a slash?
See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-querystring-parameters

By default those query strings are properly escaped, so all is well without any hacks on your end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rawurlencode()` to esacpe special characters.